# PowerShell switch conditional statement using -Parallel parameter

Tags: powershell

While in Microsoft PowerShell ISE and creating a switch statement, Intellisense gave me the available option for a switch statement and one of them was `-Parallel`.

[image: PowerShell ISE Intellisense showing the -Parallel paramater for a switch statement]

The local help for `about_switch` does not list `-Parallel` as an option for a switch statement. I'm using PowerShell version 5.1.17713.1000

Can anyone give me a explanation, case scenario, or an example of a switch statement using the `-Parallel` parameter?

Comment: Well, I don't think i have a practical example that I could get working but I can tell you this. `-Parallel` can only be used in PowerShell `Workflows`. However, there are a lot of restrictions to how you can use `Switch` inside a workflow. Perhaps this will help: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/